# show Toolbar on html page on mouse hover.(Similar to twitter when hovered over tweet)

Tags: html, css

In my website, I want to show the toolbar with options when User hover over any reply. The functionality similar to when we hover over the tweet in twitter. How can I achieve this.

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple HTML/CSS mockup I tried...

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    Testing text!
    <div class="tooltip">Here's a tooltip</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    Testing text!
    <div class="tooltip">Here's a tooltip</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    Testing text!
    <div class="tooltip">Here's a tooltip</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip { display: none; }
.container { width: 300px; height: 50px; margin: 10px 0px; border: 1px solid #000; }

.container:hover > div.tooltip { display: block; }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYxqx/)

The idea is that you have your tooltip div contained within another div which holds your content.  This tooltip's default `display` is set to `none`.  Then you have the CSS `.container:hover > div.tooltip { display: block; }` which states "when the container class is hovered over, the child of a div with a class of tooltip will change to `display: block`".  This is also very easily done with Javascript, but I figure this should suffice for what you're looking for.  Hope this helped!

Comment: thanx, this is what i am looking for with little modification.I have just changed the container to position:relative and tooltip div to position absolute: to ensure that tooltip(or toolbar) will apear at the same location and even over the content.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to help!  If you found my answer helpful I'd appreciate you up-voting it as well.